# Why isn't Dir showing files in an imported package?

Tags: python, github, directory, package, filesystems

I cloned the OpenAI whisper repository [here](https://github.com/openai/whisper). Then I imported whisper to access the whisper package. Then I used dir(whisper) to view the contents of the folder, expecting to see the file names.

Instead the output was this:

```
['__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__']
```

Comment: Dir.. so you use windows? Try ```dir /a``` and have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir

Comment: Why does dir() automatically mean windows? The python documentation says nothing about windows. I'm using Jupyter Notebooks on a Mac with an OS system

Comment: Same thing with your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.